# Why is the ghost of the crazy guy so much more powerful than the other ghosts in The Frighteners?

Tags: movie, the-frighteners

In [The Frighteners](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116365/), why was Bartlett, the ghost of the crazy guy in the black hood so much more powerful than the other ghosts? After Micheal J Fox shot him to pieces, it turns out he wasn't any different than the others. In fact, I think he is even portrayed as slightly weaker, with him having to have his girlfriend do the killings. He was even scared when Fox was just about to slice him with his own scythe.

Why was he so much more powerful than everyone else before that? What made him so special than the other ghosts? Was it the scythe and the hood? If it was, how did he get hold of such items in the first place?

Comment: The end of the film has a number of ouija boards found at the girlfriend's house, suggesting that Bartlett may have been pulled back to unlife on Earth, possibly from the Hell he's sent to in the climax of the film. That said, I don't think that's spelled out in the film.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out a copy of the 10th anniversary version from the library. I watched it last night just by itself, since I hadn't seen the film before. From that perspective, I don't think it's a matter of Bartlett actually being that much more powerful. He does have the scythe, which seems to be able to do permanent damage to the ghosts, sending them on to the afterlife. It's implied in the course of the film that he may have taken both the cloak and the scythe from the actual Grim Reaper in his escape from Hell, one likely enacted by Patricia with the help of the Ouija boards, as seen at the end.

What Bartlett does have is determination, and purpose. We see the example among the ghosts of Hiles, seemingly unaffected by the years, and the one who gives Bartlett the most challenge early on. Similarly, Bannister is highly motivated in his purpose (and has the advantage of being prepared for his death and afterlife by knowing what is to come). Lastly, both Bannister and Bartlett have love on their side.

So, TL;DR, highly motivated individual who may be carrying an afterlife artifact.